# Create a screen with a textbox and a button completely written in NDK without using JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I wanted to develop an application that is completely written in C++ using NDK with NativeActivity.

This application will show a screen on startup that will show a Textbox with a label associated with it and a button with its text on it.

I want to write this completely in C++, is this possible ? If yes, please give me some pointers so that I can proceed. Currently I am not able to think on how can I do it.

Comment: Download the NDK and look at the native-activity sample that comes with it. Then go through the available APIs to see what you can and cannot do from native code. If something still is unclear at that point, please specify exactly what you're trying to do, _how_ you're trying to do it, and the error(s) you're getting.

Comment: I have already gone through the native-activity sample and I have understood. Also I have already explained what I am trying to do but  How should I go about it that I am not clear and that is my question here.